# "Younger ... elder ..." vs "younger one ... elder one ..."

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Should one write "younger one ... elder one ..." or it's not necessary to add the "one"?

Example sentence:

> I grew up with two sisters. One time, the younger (one) asked the elder (one) to borrow her a dress for her first date.

Comment: Once, the younger one asked the older one if she could borrow her dress for her first date. Borrow my car. Borrow my jeans. BUT: lend my dress to her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English both "elder" and "younger" may be nouns or adjectives.

You can create phrases like the "elder brother" to refer to an older brother (implying that there is a younger brother).  And you can also say the one must respect one's elders (implying those older than you).  It really comes down to context and what you are trying to emphasize.

Getting back to your sentence, what are you trying to state?  From the context, there are three of you.  Alex is a gender-neutral name.  If you are one of the sisters, then the sentence is a bit ambiguous. However, if you are their brother, then the elder/younger can be either way.

I would change the sentence at the "...to borrow her a dress..." part.  Just remove the "her".

Answer (score 1):

When used as adjectives, as is the case in your example, you must have a noun for them to modify.

> Younger *sister*
> Younger *one*
> Younger *sibling*

As adjectives, they can also modify phrases:

> She is the younger *of the two sisters.*

And in this case, the noun *sisters* can be omitted if it is contextually understood:

> She has a sister, and she is the younger *of the two.*

In spoken English you will hear "she has a sister, and she is the younger," omitting the entire clause.  However, that is not grammatically correct.

In English, "younger" and "elder" are also nouns.<sup>1</sup>

> Church *Elder*
> Tribal *Elder*
> Children should listen to their *Elders.*

So, please remember:

- Adjectives (e.g., *elder one*) require an object to modify, a noun or a clause.
- Nouns to not require modification (e.g., *I spoke to he elders.*)

---

<sup>1</sup> *@JeremyC complained about my bold, blanket statement that "younger" wasn't a noun.  I'm not perfect, but I am a well-trained and well-read technical writer and general editor.  I've never seen or heard "younger" used as a noun in my life and the [example provided by Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/younger) sounds funny.  In fact, I would have considered the statement ungrammatical, the word "younger" being an adjective and the sentence missing the noun "brother."  That's why you don't see any noun examples using "younger" in my answer.  If you think about it, who cares about getting advice from the youngers of your village or the youngers of your church?  I apologize for my rant, but I consider this much ado about a very small issue that doesn't affect the outcome of my answer at all.  But, all knowledge is good.  "Younger" is considered both a noun and an adjective.  Son of a gun.*

Comment: Please give your source for the surprising statement that 'the younger"' is grammatically correct.

Comment: @JeremyC, what surprising statement are you talking about?  As I say in my answer, "younger" isn't a noun in English (unlike "elder"), so "the younger sister" would be correct, but "the younger" isn't.

Comment: @JeremyC, oh... you mean in my spoken English example.  However, I specifically state that while it will be heard, it is not grammatically correct.  Did you read my answer carefully?

Comment: I did. Very carefully.  I still think that you are wrong, unless you can produce some very authoritative reference that shows what you regard as acceptable in informal language is forbidden in formal language.'Younger isn't a noun in English' -, who says?

Comment: @JeremyC, fair enough.  I went and checked, and Merriam-Webster indeed claims ["younger" can be a noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/younger).  Even their example sounds funny.  I've never once heard "younger" used as a noun in my life.  But, there it is.  I'll update my answer.  Cheers.